# How to obliterate (totally delete) a contact?

Tags: contacts

I have android devices with WhatsApp and another apps. When I try delete any contact, sometimes in the next days the contact backs to my contact list... In the end, I need most of times block the contact on WhatsApp to avoid use it. I think that some app is recovering/syncing the contact back, but I updated the Google Contacts, removing the contact and he keeps returning...

This is the reason why I use the term "obliterate", I see when learning source control... When you delete a file from source control, it is deleted, but you can recover from the history/previous commits. So when you want fully delete, you want "obliterate" it, pretending like it never existed...

I wonder if can have 5 options for deal with this:

1. Some option on Android to obliterate (I search but not found)
2. Some app with that option or that objective
3. Some app to monitor and block the contact to back to list
4. Some app to monitor and discover the app that is recovering the contact
5. Some app with the job of maintain the master list of contact, and from there I delete it and the app keeps "deleted", monitoring the contact list changes

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I used **Wondershare MobileGo** for same issue and also for removing duplicate contacts. **It worked for me** well. If it doesn't work too, there might be some another agent other than Google contacts which is backing up and synchronizing contacts frequently again and again.

Comment: Try deleting contacts and syncing your phone immediately after. If they re-appear log into your google Contacts (on your PC) and delete them there. Same goes for WhatsApp.